# Tiling Mars themis raster for Cesium

Tags: gdal, cesium, gdal2tiles, node-js, mars

I am trying to tile the Mars [themis](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Mars/Odyssey/THEMIS-IR-Mosaic-ASU/Mars_MO_THEMIS-IR-Day_mosaic_global_100m_v12) raster that has the following crs:

```
PROJCS["SimpleCylindrical Mars",
    GEOGCS["GCS_Mars",
        DATUM["D_Mars",
            SPHEROID["Mars",3396190,0]],
        PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Equirectangular"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",180],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

The `--profile` option in `gdal2tiles` can be `geodetic`, `mercator` or `raster`. Given the projection of the input raster above, I tile the raster as follows:

```
gdal2tiles.py --zoom=0-7 --profile raster input.tif output/
```

However, Cesium.js is unable to consume these tiles because it only supports a tiling scheme of either `geodetic` or `mercator`.

Is there a workaround?